# How to enable pstore for kernel panics on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kernel, error-handling

##### What I have:

- Ubuntu 18.04 server with HWE 5.4.0-136 kernel
- systemd-237 (without `systemd-pstore` service).
- `/sys/module/pstore/parameters/backend` contains `(null)`
- `pstore` is automatically mounted to `/sys/fs/pstore`
- EFI-related messages in `dmesg | grep -i efi`:

  ```
  ACPI: UEFI 0x000000003B55B7B8 000048 (v01 ALASKA A M I    00000002      01000013)
  ACPI: Reserving UEFI table memory at [mem 0x3b55b7b8-0x3b55b7ff]
  ```
- Pstore-related vars in `/boot/config`:

  ```
  CONFIG_EFI_VARS_PSTORE=m
  # CONFIG_EFI_VARS_PSTORE_DEFAULT_DISABLE is not set
  CONFIG_CHROMEOS_PSTORE=m
  CONFIG_PSTORE=y
  CONFIG_PSTORE_DEFLATE_COMPRESS=y
  # CONFIG_PSTORE_LZO_COMPRESS is not set
  # CONFIG_PSTORE_LZ4_COMPRESS is not set
  # CONFIG_PSTORE_LZ4HC_COMPRESS is not set
  # CONFIG_PSTORE_842_COMPRESS is not set
  # CONFIG_PSTORE_ZSTD_COMPRESS is not set
  CONFIG_PSTORE_COMPRESS=y
  CONFIG_PSTORE_DEFLATE_COMPRESS_DEFAULT=y
  CONFIG_PSTORE_COMPRESS_DEFAULT="deflate"
  # CONFIG_PSTORE_CONSOLE is not set
  # CONFIG_PSTORE_PMSG is not set
  # CONFIG_PSTORE_FTRACE is not set
  CONFIG_PSTORE_RAM=m
  ```

##### What I want:

- access dmesg after kernel panic.

##### What I did:

- `vi /etc/default/grub`

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pstore.backend=efi efi_pstore.pstore_disable=0"
  ```
- `update-grub`
- `vi /etc/sysctl.d/KernelPanic.conf`

  ```
  kernel.panic=30
  ```
- `vi /etc/modules-load.d/KernelPanic.conf`

  ```
  efi_pstore
  ramoops
  ```

##### After reboot:

- `lsmod` reports that modules are loaded, but without messages in `dmesg`
- `/sys/module/pstore/parameters/backend` contains `efi`
- `dmesg | grep -i pstore` displays kernel cmdline only

##### Initiate panic:

```
echo 65535 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
sync
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

##### After restart:

- `/sys/fs/pstore` is empty -- why?